# What is the checkout of Circle Ci doing?

Tags: circleci

What is the checkout of Circle Ci doing?

I have a master branch and a develop branch.

When I run git push origin master, does circle ci only pull the master branch?

Does the develop branch do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you update a branch on GitHub, CircleCI builds the HEAD of that branch. If you push a git tag, it'll built the commit the tag points to.

In your scenario, if you push to master, it'll build the HEAD of master, which is the most recent commit of master. Other branches are irrelevant in that scenario.

Also, the checkout step specifically is git cloning your project, and the checking out the specific commit to build.